# Acumatica Side Panel linked to detail item

Tags: acumatica

I'm using Acumatica 2020R1 and I'm adding side panels. Is there anyway, for example on the PO form (PO301000), that I could link a side panel to update when clicking on the Document Details?

Answer (score 2):

​
I actually discovered a way to do this on Acumatica 2020R1. Here's how I did it:

Edit: I did this for the SOOrderEntry screen, creating a side panel that looks at the SOOrder but uses parameters from the SOLine. This method will work for any two tables with a master-detail relationship by replacing SOOrder & SOLine accordingly.

Part A:

1. Create virtual fields on the SOOrder DAC that correlate to the SOLine Parameters you need
2. Update these as lines are selecting/updated using event handlers
3. pass these fields as the params to your side panel actions as you normally would

While It seems like this alone would work, the side panel actually doesn’t refresh when a new SOLine is selected. We’re going to have to get creative to resolve this issue.

Part B:

1. Create an additional virtual field on the SOOrder DAC to keep track of which side panel was last opened (I will explain how to track this later). I use a string field to do so. This is especially important if you have more than one side panel on your screen.
2. Next you want to define a standard graph action that will update this field. Make it Visible = false, since you don’t actually want this button to show. We will call if from behind the scenes later. This is the method I use:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> SidePanelCallback;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "SidePanelCallback", Visible = false)]
public virtual IEnumerable sidePanelCallback(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    SOOrder doc = Base.Document.Current;
    if (doc == null) return adapter.Get();

    var docExt = doc.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
    docExt.UsrSidePanelDetailParamsRefresh = adapter.CommandArguments;

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

*Note: docExt.UsrSidePanelDetailParamRefresh is the variable I for the previous step

3. Now you need a way to trigger your code when your side panel actions are called. To do this we’ll use the following JavaScript

```
function commandResult(ds, context) {
    var ds = px_alls['ds'];
    switch (context.command) 
    {
        case ('JustAction'):
            ds.executeCallback('GraphAction', 'parameter value');
            break;
    }
}
```

You want to replace JustAction with the internal name of your side panel action. it should look like this: NavigateToLayer$DB000028
where DB000028 is the target ScreenID for your sidepanel. If you want to make sure your actions follow the same naming convention, you can check it by adding breakpoints and checking with the debugger.
You should replace GraphAction with the name of the graph action you created in the previous step. In our case SidePanelCallback
Then finally for the parameter value pass whatever you’d like to use to identify the opened side panel. This will be stored in UsrSidePanelDetailParamRefresh, or your equivalent.
You can create a case statement for each side panel you want this functionality for, so you only have to do all this once per graph!
Then finally, attach your script to the client event ‘commandPerformed’ on your data source.

4. Next we will define another graph action to do the actual refresh of the side panel. Mine looks like this:

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> SidePanelRefresh;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "SidePanelRefresh", Visible = false)]
public virtual IEnumerable sidePanelRefresh(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    SOOrder doc = Base.Document.Current;
    if (doc == null) return adapter.Get();

    var docExt = doc.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();

    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string[] args = adapter.CommandArguments.Split('*');
    switch (docExt.UsrSidePanelDetailParamsRefresh)
    {
        case ("Component Inventory"):
            parameters.Add("Kit", args[0]);
            parameters.Add("SiteID", args[1]);
            throw new PXRedirectToGIRequiredException("Component Inventory", parameters) { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Layer };
    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

**Note that for my use case the parameters I am passing cannot contain the character ‘*’, so I use it as a delimiter**
And again, you can define as many case statements as you need for each of your dynamic side panels.

5. And now finally we need javascript again to call this action. Using event handlers are too slow for this type of refresh, they will always pass the old SOLine parameters. If you know a way to avoid javascript here, I’d love to hear it, as doing callbacks like this does have a heavy overhead. Because of this, be careful where you attach this script to, I actually attach it to the grid’s RowSelectorClick client event rather than AfterRowChange for this reason, and train my users to select rows in this way (by clicking the arrow to the left of each row) so we don’t impact the rest of the company for the minority that use this feature. I’d recommend this if you're working on a high traffic screen such as SO301000.
   Anyway, here’s the javascript:

```
function Side_Panel_Refresh() {
    px_alls["ds"].executeCallback("SidePanelRefresh", this.func.caller.arguments[2].row.getCell("InventoryID").getValue() + "*" + this.func.caller.arguments[2].row.getCell("SiteID").getValue());
}
```

SidePanelRefresh: Name of our graph action from the previous step.
InventoryID & SiteID are my parameters.
And again, using ‘*’ as a delimiter.

Anyway, I hope this helps anyone looking to make dynamic side panels. If anyone has improvements on this method I’d love to hear constructive feedback.

Happy development!

​

Comment: Thanks for this! It was extremely helpful. In my experience, the JS is doing basically all the work. I don't need to update the field values, because they aren't actually being used anywhere. The JS is pulling the values directly out of the SOLine, not the SOOrder. In fact, you don't even need the fields on SOOrder, because the side panel doesn't need the parameters tied in. They just need to match the parameters passed through JS. I also eliminated the SidePanelCallback, because if I'm clicking the grid row selector, it will be to load this side panel. Blissfully simple, and working in 22R2

Answer (score 0):

It is a new feature. Side panel were restricted to generic inquiry. In version 2020 you still need a generic inquiry to configure the side panel but they can be viewed in data entry forms too.

[image]

The feature is implemented with wizards so it's pretty limited in what it can do. Currently you are limited to the choices available in navigation parameter. It seems like it's not possible to add details entity there. Maybe there's a way but I'm not aware of it.

Check documentation reference link for `User Interface: Side Panels for Data Entry Forms` (content copied below): 
https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=a11aa71b-5f18-4c8f-9c69-350f2c7a89f4

Adding a Side Panel to the Data Entry Form
A customizer can add multiple side panel navigation paths to a data entry form.

To add a side panel, the customizer navigates to the Customization Projects (SM204505) form and creates a new project.

In the Customization Project Editor, the customizer selects the screen for which the side panel is planned to be added.

On the Screens > Form ID > Actions, the customizer adds an action of the Navigation:

Side panel type (1), specifies general settings (2), adds destination screen (3), and specifies parameters (4), if needed (for instance, in the screenshot below, Business Account was selected as a parameter so that the side panel displayed the cases of the specific customer selected on the data entry form).

Example of a side panel on the Customers form
[image]
To apply the changes, the customizer must publish the created customization project.